# Python update dictionary into dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am very novice in python, and I am currently learning the language. I found that array of arrays ( associative arrays ) are called as dictionaries in python ({})
I am facing a problem. I need to build a dictionary and update it in a `for` loop. My codes are below.

```
loc = {}
result = { I get the list of records from database here, which has id and status }
for res in result:
    temp={}
    temp['id']= res.id
    temp['status'] = res.status
    loc.update(temp) # this replaces the values every time, i want append

print loc
```

below is the result expected by me:

```
loc = { {'id' : 123 , 'status' : 'available' },
        { 'id' : 456 , 'status' : 'unavailable'}
       }
```

Can someone help me. I tried with :

```
loc = [] # [] this works with loc.append(temp) 
this gives result as : 
[{'id' : 123 , 'status' : 'available'},{'id' : 456 , 'status' : 'unavailable'}]
```

But i need the above result with dictionary of dictionaries in python.

Comment: Your expected result `loc` is not a dict, as it does not contain keys and values. In a dict of dicts, you have keys whose values are dictionaries. What do you intend to use as the keys? Why does `loc` need to be a dict of dicts? A list of dicts, as shown in your bottom result, seems to work fine.

Comment: Dictionary is a key-value pair (indexed by the key). Now what is the key for the outer dictionary?

Comment: Why is loc a dictionary?

Comment: "Arrays of arrays" is not really a good way to think of a `dict`. A `dict` is a hash table or hash map, with fast look up properties. In Python, the `list` is what's commonly used where you might be use an array in other languages. (There *is* something called an array in Python, but it's rarely used.)

Comment: Does every result have a unique `id`? Are `id` and `status` the only fields you are interested in?

Comment: @MattDMo Actually, I think maybe it is relevant in a kind of sideways way. The wording the OP used was suggestive of a PHP background, and I think the fact that PHP has "arrays" and "associative arrays" ended up confusing the OP about the nature of the data structures and what data structures are appropriate in Python.

Comment: @jpmc26 good point. I rolled back to the OP's original text.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so, please accept an answer; you can write your own if neither of the existing ones are sufficient. If not, then please clarify why the answers didn't solve your problem.

Comment: Well jpmc26, For me both answers worked, that's why i haven't selected one.

Comment: If you are learning Python, you should *not* be investing time in learning Python 2. Those of us who still write it do so because we have to support or migrate legacy code.

Answer (score 2):

If `id` is unique, it seems more likely that what you really want is just a `dict` mapping `id` to `status`.

```
for res in result:
    loc[res.id] = res.status
```

If you iterate over `loc.viewitems()` (in Py3, just `loc.items()`), you get `tuple`s that pair each `id` with its `status`; Python uses `tuple`s as sort of "anonymous lightweight objects", so it works quite similarly to the `set` of `dict`s you were trying to build. Used this way, you can look up values by `id` efficiently (`loc[someid]` will get you the associated `status` if the `id` exists or raise `KeyError`), while still being able to efficiently iterate them:

```
for ID, status in loc.viewitems():
    # do stuff with ID and status
```

A `list` of `dict`s makes lookup a `O(n)` task (where the plain `dict` is roughly `O(1)` lookup), and makes iteration a little more ugly, requiring you to use `operator.itemgetter` to write a similar loop for unpacking, or requiring manual lookup of the both `id` and `status` for each item, which is ugly to say the least. It's also much less efficient memory-wise; each two item `dict` pays fairly substantial memory overhead relative to a single larger `dict`.

One other option to consider, if you really want this to behave more like JS objects, is using `collections.namedtuple`. It's sort of `dict` like; you access attributes with dot syntax, not keys with bracket syntax, but it's much more memory efficient, and it's immutable, so it can go in a `set`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Record = namedtuple('Record', 'id status')

loc = {Record(res.id, res.status) for res in result}
```

You can then use the `namedtuple` like a regular `tuple` (so `for ID, status in loc:` works), or use named attribute access instead:

```
for record in loc:
    print(record.id, record.status)
```

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger

Answer (score 1):

What you say is your desired output:

```
loc = {
    {'id' : 123 , 'status' : 'available' },
    {'id' : 456 , 'status' : 'unavailable'}
}
```

would not be a `dict`. It would be a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) if it worked at all.

But a `set` can't contain a `dict` because it's not hashable. A set can only contain hashable elements because it uses the hash for fast lookups. (A hashable item would either be completely immutable or any mutation it experiences would not affect the hash. Note that not affecting the hash implies it also doesn't affect equality. Generally, it's just easier to ensure hashable things are immutable.)

In a dictionary, you *must* have a **key** and a **value**. Your desired output does not describe a key for each inner `dict`, so a `dict` isn't the data structure you want. What you probably want is exactly what you found out works:

```
loc = [
    {'id' : 123 , 'status' : 'available' },
    {'id' : 456 , 'status' : 'unavailable'}
]
```

This is a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list). A `list` is the go-to data structure for holding a sequence of elements. You can iterate over it:

```
for i in loc:
    print(i)
```

or access elements of it via index:

```
loc[2]
```

This is probably what you want. There's more you can do with it, like [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1394393) it, but I won't get into everything here.

The [`update`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) function you are calling in your sample code is used for taking each key in the input `dict` and either adding the key/value pair to it or updating the value for an existing key. You might think of this as "merging" the argument `dict` into the one before the dot. That's why it overwrote all the values each time; that's how it's supposed to work. Python's documentation is pretty good; you want to get in the habit of consulting it whenever something doesn't behave as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can update a dictionary by adding a new entry or a key-value pair, modifying an existing entry, or deleting an existing entry as shown below in the simple example

```
dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}

dict['Age'] = 8; # update existing entry
dict['School'] = "DPS School"; # Add new entry


print "dict['Age']: ", dict['Age']
print "dict['School']: ", dict['School']
```

source: [iodocs](https://iodocs.com/python/dictionary/)